# Convertir a pdf en angular

Tags: angular, api, pdf

Resulta que estoy trabajando en una api nest donde devuelve un documento pdf a modo de texto. ¿Existe una librería para traer ese archivo como PDF?
Para que me entiendan: esta es la respuesta de la API:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Czi.png

Esta es la forma como estoy trayendo el documento:

```
    return this.http.get(this.urlSeeDocument+id+'.pdf');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los curiosos, encontré la respuesta en este link, espero que les sirva :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300252/angular2-displaying-pdf